# How to query for specific person on Wikidata using SparQL?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am making a [query](https://query.wikidata.org/#PREFIX%20schema%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2F%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3Fperson%20%3FpersonLabel%20%3Fpic%20%3FgivenName%20%3FgivenNameLabel%20%3FfamilyName%20%3FfamilyNameLabel%20%3FplaceOfBirth%20%3FplaceOfBirthLabel%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5%20.%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP18%20%3Fpic%20.%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP735%20%3FgivenName%20.%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP734%20%3FfamilyName%20.%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP19%20%3FplaceOfBirth%20.%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP569%20%3FbirthDate%20.%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20%3Flabel%20%22Einstein%22%40en%20.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fcid%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AinLanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3E%20.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0ALIMIT%201) which I think would make sense, but it is just hanging, no error:

```
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>

SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?person ?personLabel ?pic ?givenName ?givenNameLabel ?familyName ?familyNameLabel ?placeOfBirth ?placeOfBirthLabel
WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5 .
  ?person wdt:P18 ?pic .
  ?person wdt:P735 ?givenName .
  ?person wdt:P734 ?familyName .
  ?person wdt:P19 ?placeOfBirth .
  ?person wdt:P569 ?birthDate .
  ?item ?label "Einstein"@en .
  OPTIONAL {
    ?article schema:about ?cid .
    ?article schema:inLanguage "en" .
    ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/> .
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
LIMIT 1
```

How do I query for a person using their **Wikipedia** page name, and get this sort of information?

Unhelpfully, it finally timed out with:

```
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
        at com.bigdata.rdf.sail.webapp.BigdataServlet.submitApiTask(BigdataServlet.java:292)
        at com.bigdata.rdf.sail.webapp.QueryServlet.doSparqlQuery(QueryServlet.java:678)
        at com.bigdata.rdf.sail.webapp.QueryServlet.doGet(QueryServlet.java:290)
        at com.bigdata.rdf.sail.webapp.RESTServlet.doGet(RESTServlet.java:240)
        at com.bigdata.rdf.sail.webapp.MultiTenancyServlet.doGet(MultiTenancyServlet.java:273)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.blazegraph.throttling.ThrottlingFilter.doFilter(ThrottlingFilter.java:320)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.blazegraph.throttling.SystemOverloadFilter.doFilter(SystemOverloadFilter.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.helpers.MDCInsertingServletFilter.doFilter(MDCInsertingServletFilter.java:49)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.blazegraph.filters.QueryEventSenderFilter.doFilter(QueryEventSenderFilter.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.blazegraph.filters.ClientIPFilter.doFilter(ClientIPFilter.java:43)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.blazegraph.filters.JWTIdentityFilter.doFilter(JWTIdentityFilter.java:66)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.blazegraph.filters.RealAgentFilter.doFilter(RealAgentFilter.java:33)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.blazegraph.filters.RequestConcurrencyFilter.doFilter(RequestConcurrencyFilter.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1340)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1242)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:503)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Comment: your problem is clearly a copy-paste error ... `?item ?label "Einstein"@en .` is not connected to the rest of the query, which makes it horrible for the query as a huge join will happen. You should make it `?person ?label "Einstein"@en .` - and then indeed also fix the part where you `SELECT` the variables. There is no more any `?item` in your query then

Comment: there is also no connection of the `OPTIONAL` part to the rest of the query - I mean, where is `?cid` in your query? Also make it `?person` please. Note, without connected variables, those patterns will result in a cartesian product - which in fact is huge here

Comment: `SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?pic ?givenName ?givenNameLabel ?familyName ?familyNameLabel ?placeOfBirth ?placeOfBirthLabel
WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5 .
  ?person wdt:P18 ?pic .
  ?person wdt:P735 ?givenName .
  ?person wdt:P734 ?familyName .
  ?person wdt:P19 ?placeOfBirth .
  ?person wdt:P569 ?birthDate .
  ?person ?label "Einstein"@en .
  OPTIONAL {
    ?article schema:about ?person .
    ?article schema:inLanguage "en" .
    ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/> .
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
LIMIT 1`

Comment: for the future, a maybe more promising search option you should have a look at is the MWAPI extension: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual/MWAPI - that will avoid to exactly match the text properties and is closer to IR methods